# Icons show up late in games folder

Tags: icons, gaming, user-folders

I am using Windows 10 , build 1903

When I Open my game folder, the icons show up late and I must wait for about 15s to see all the games' icons. At first I see them as a white paper icon (the same icon for all of them) and then slowly the icons of each game show up. I don't have any other folder like this. This folder is on my desktop and in my SSD, and my games folder has 41 icons.

Comment: Does this happen in any other folders? How many icons? What kind of computer?

Comment: I don't have any other folder like this . also this folder is on my desktop and in ssd.  my game folder has 41 icon

Comment: Please edit the question itself to add requested information. Please add ALL information that has been requested. Right now we do not have enough information to indicate what the actual problem is, and we request at least what has been requested in order to do so.

Comment: @music2myear Darth edited this question and provided some of the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the icon cache is to display icons more quickly, so that you don't have to load them every time you try to access the file. Rebuild the icon cache (in Windows 10) or the thumbnail cache (in Windows 7 and 8) by finding and deleting the cache file so that Windows rebuilds it on the next restart.

You are using Windows 10, build 1903. To clear the icons cache in Windows 10, follow [these instructions](https://neosmart.net/wiki/clear-icons-cache/):

> 1. Open Windows Explorer.
> 2. From the *View* tab, select *Hidden items*.
> 3. Select *Show selected items*.
> 4. Go to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`, where `C:\` is the drive where you installed Windows and `User` is the
>      username of your account profile.
> 5. Select all files that begin with `iconcache`.
> 6. Right­-click on these files.
> 7. Click *Delete*. To delete these files faster, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> keys.

If that doesn’t work, follow these steps for increasing the icon cache size in Windows 7, 8, and 10.

1. Click the Windows Start menu and type `regedit`.
2. Right-click on *Run command* below regedit and select *Run as administrator*.
3. Backup your registry before preceding by selecting *File* -> *Export* and then name the backup file and click the *Save* button to save it.
4. In the left pane unfold *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE* -> *SOFTWARE* -> *Microsoft* -> *Windows* -> *CurrentVersion* -> *Explorer*.
5. Select Explorer by clicking it. Right-click on Explorer and select *New* -> *String Value*.
6. Rename this new string value `Max Cached Icons`.
7. Double-click on *Max Cached Icons* after renaming it. In the *Value data* text entry field type `4096`. This sets the Max Cached Icons size to 4MB, but you can type a larger or smaller number.
8. Click the OK button to save the changed setting for max cached icons size which will also close the registry editor.
9. Restart Windows to enable the change in the registry max cached icons size setting.

Comment: tnx for your advice, but unfortunately none of them worked. while I tried the first way I couldn't delete the icons file , i think just 3 of them removed. and the second way I even increased the size of cached icons to 16m (16000) and it didn't work either ,